# In which 80s childrens TV series is a pre-industrial future world ruled by 3-legged robots?

Tags: story-identification

The story takes place in an undefined future where society has reverted to a pre-industrial stage. The world is ruled by huge three-legged robots. At a certain age every child gets an implant that removes all its creativity, curiosity and passion, turning them into compliant, mellow sheep.

Before he receives his implant the hero of the story escapes with his friend (a Samweis Gamdschie-like sidekick). On their journey through the in-fact post-apocalyptic world they discover that the world was once way more advanced and that the robots are alien oppressors.

Comment: +1 just because I'd never seen the German transliteration of Samwise Gamgee before.  :)

Comment: @mskfisher: lol, thanks! Didn't even noticed it was a transliteration...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Book: [The Tripods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods) by John Christopher.

> The story of *The Tripods* is a variation on post-apocalyptic literature, wherein humanity has been enslaved by "Tripods" — gigantic three-legged walking machines, piloted by unseen alien entities (later identified as "Masters"). Human society is largely pastoral, with few habitations larger than villages, and what little industry exists is conducted under the watchful presence of the Tripods. Lifestyle is reminiscent of the Middle Ages, but small artifacts from the Modern Age are still used, such as watches.
>
> Humans are controlled from the age of 14 by implants called "Caps," which suppress individuality and free will. Some people, whose minds are broken by the Caps, become vagrants. According to The City of Gold and Lead, Masters begin to believe that humans should be capped at an earlier age "because some humans, in the year or two before they are Capped, become rebellious and act against the masters", but this cannot be done, because Capping must wait until the braincase has stopped growing

TV Series: [The Tripods](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086818/)

> Earth has been conquered by an alien race known as the Masters using their giant Tripods. When humans reach the age of sixteen, they must undergo a process known as capping which places their mind under the control of the conquerors. In 2089, having learned the truth, cousins Will and Henry Parker embark on a journey to the White Mountains in search of a group of free men.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Great! Love this place :-)

Comment: Great book series! For the time the TV Series was The Bomb, but in re-watching... well you judge: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hYJumW_G8E

Comment: The TV series was incredibly popular here in Germany (in part of course because there where only three TV channels to choose from and SciFi series were pretty rare) - if you ask any german fourty-something with at least a passing interest in SciFi about his fav series from his youth chances are that he'll become all starry-eyed and recount the plot of The Tripods.

Comment: As a German I can second that. I was way too young when the show was on so I didn't recall it's name. Still the pictures and the story were so unusual too my eyes and ears, they burnt into my memory.

Comment: BTW - the theme music was awesome!

Comment: Since german is involved here, for completeness the german title is "Die dreibeinigen Herrscher"

Comment: We only had four channels in the UK at the time.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, but you had Dr. Who, The Avengers and Sir Patrick Moore so I don't feel you have any reason to complain :-).

Comment: I remember it because it was serialized as a comic over the course of several years in "Boys' Life" magazine, the official magazine of the Boy Scouts of America.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: and we still do! Well, one out of three :(

Answer (score 1):

The "Tripods" TV series was based on John Christopher's trilogy:
1. "The White Mountains"
2. "The City of Gold And Lead"
3. "The Pool of Fire"