# I'm looking for the title of a post-apocalyptic children's sci-fi TV series of the mid-1980s, which followed a flooded Britain

Tags: story-identification, tv

The series was taken off air mid-way through the run, as it was deemed too scary.

Comment: Can you offer any more information such as any specific events, character names, who the villains were, etc?

Answer (score 6):

The only show I can think of that comes close to this description is the 1984 TV series "[The Tripods](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods_%28TV_series%29)" which features several children in leading roles and regularly had them traipsing through waterlogged countryside.

The show *was* cancelled before its finale season but because of poor ratings (e.g. versus the cost of production) rather than because it was too scary

Comment: Hmmm, this is the 2nd 'story identification' question about The Tripods posted in the last few weeks... [HERE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53540/in-which-80s-childrens-tv-series-is-a-pre-industrial-future-world-ruled-by-3-leg)

Answer (score 2):

The British post-apocalyptic children's series that was never finished was The Tripods, but that had nothing to do with flooding and was not taken off-air because it was too scary, but  simply because the budget was cut.